# how to give dynamic route path in include in pug template

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, templates, pug

want to make dynamic include

example-
h1
include path/#{object}
or
include path/+{object}+{a:true,b:11}
something like above and if any one know how to do with Mixins in pug please give an example for include

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic path for `extends`, `include` is not possible, because the pug compiler expects the path as a string rather than interpolating the path.

Comment: so whats the other ways to achieve dynamic routing ,it is because i am converting ejs template into pug template ,if possible please explain with example